# Properties of a probability distribution function

Tags: probability-distributions, continuity

Let X be a random variable and let $F_X$ be its probability distribution function.

For each statements state whether it is always true, sometimes true or never true.

a) $F_X$ is right continuous

b) {$F_X(x)$, x $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$ } fully determines the distribution function of the random variable $X$

c) $F_X$ is left continuous

d) $F_X(x)$ = $F_X(x^+)$ $\forall$$x$ $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$

Attempt:

b - always true
d- always true

How can I know if $F_X$ is always/sometimes right and/or left continuous?

Comment: Hey Car! This reads like homework. I think you'll get better answers if you explained where you get stuck!

Comment: I'm particularly stuck with a and c. How do I know if the cdf is always right continuous and/or left continuous? I'm aware it should be always continuous at one of those.

Comment: Do you mind confirming my answer to b and d? Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you add exactly that concern about a) and c) to your question text itself? Questions are supposed to be "complete in themselves", and this is a really important aspect!

Comment: I can't say anything about b) and d) aside from that you'd earn 0 points in an exam that I state if you're not showing how you've arrived at your solution!

Comment: I believe that a property of cdf is being right continuous and that $F_X(x)=F_X(x^+)$  is a property, am I right? @MarcusMüller

Comment: reduce the "I believe" down to a "I know, because..."! Believing is not really a proof…

Answer (score 1):

> How can I know if $F_X$ is always/sometimes right and/or left continuous?

Deduction!

Since this is homework, I'll give you the necessary hints to solve this yourself:

Can it be "always left- and right-continuous"  at the same time? How do we call functions that are both left- and right-continuous? (The answer to this is easy.) Are CDFs always such functions?

Assuming it's only one of right- and left-continuos, try finding an easy example where at least one of these must be wrong. Test your hypothesis by finding the relevant point and apply the definitions of "left-continuous" and "right-continuous" at that specific point (that's easier than it sounds! Ask yourself how $F_X$ is defined in terms of probability!)

Comment: CDFs can be continuous or discontinuous, but it is always right continuous (it is a property). From this, we know that C is sometimes true, and A and D is always true. B is also always true because we know that the derivative/jumps in the cdf generates the pdf. Can you confirm this?

Comment: good work! I'm sure you've also been told the reason *why* it's always right-continuous (you weren't asked this question because it's necessary that you know this by heart, but because it's necessary that you understand the reason!). You're still working on "I believe it's always right-cont", even if you don't call it believing anymore :) You can derive this, so do!

Comment: Then I assume my answers are right? Thanks a lot for your help! Appreciate it.